# Java regex for accepting a valid hostname, IPv4, or IPv6 address

Tags: java, regex, ipv6, hostname, ipv4

Does anyone have a good (preferably tested) regex for accepting only a valid DNS hostname, IPv4, or IPv6 address?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I understand that you may be *forced* to use a regex.  However, if possible it is better to avoid using regexes for this task and use a Java library class to do the validation instead.

If you want to do validation and DNS lookup together, then [`InetAddress.getByName(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) is a good choice.  This will cope with DNS, IPv4 and IPv6 in one go, and it returns you a neatly wrapped `InetAddress` instance that contains both the DNS name (if provided) and the IPv4 or IPv6 address.

If you just want to do a syntactic validation, then Apache commons has a couple of classes that should do the job: [`DomainValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.html) and [`InetAddressValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html).

Comment: Sadly it throws an exception merely because a host does not exist, not just when the host is invalid.

Comment: @Trejkaz - what "it" are you talking about?  Did you try the alternative approach too?

Comment: @StephenC yeah, my bad, I meant getByName() in particular. For DomainValidator, you can immediately see from the Javadoc that it won't work in general, because they're restricting the list of top-level domains, which is something people surely realised was a bad idea back when .eu, .asia and so forth were added and all their validation stopped working.

Comment: Well, yes, any TLD validator (like Apache `DomainValidator`) that uses a static table of TLDs is liable to get out of date.  However, that API does allow you to supply a more up to date table; see the `updateTLDOverride` method.

Answer (score 5):

Guava has a new class [HostSpecifier](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/net/HostSpecifier.html). It will even validate that the host name (if it is a host name) ends in a valid "public suffix" (e.g., ".com", ".co.uk", etc.), based on the latest mozilla public suffix list.  That's something you would NOT want to attempt with a hand-crafted regex!

Comment: I wouldn't want to trust code which has taken a snapshot of the "latest" public suffix list either, because a couple of months later it won't be the latest one.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, doing this with a regex is quite a challenge and not advisable.  But it is easy to do with the [IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) which can parse host names, IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, without triggering DNS lookup. Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Sample code:

```java
check("1.2.3.4");
check("::1");
check("a.b.com");

static void check(String hostStr) {
    HostName host = new HostName(hostStr);
    try {
        host.validate(); // triggers exception for invalid
        if(host.isAddress()) {
            IPAddress address = host.asAddress();
            System.out.println(address.getIPVersion() + " address: " + address);
        } else {
            System.out.println("host name: " + host);
        }
    } catch(HostNameException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
IPv6 address: ::1
host name: a.b.com
```

Comment: what if the hostname is not reachable from current network / protected by firewall etc? Would it throw HostNameException?

Comment: No, it doesn't check if a host name is reachable, or if it is used, it checks whether the string could potentially be a host name, whether it has a valid host name format.  It checks whether it is a valid host name.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the code I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345063/java-common-way-to-validate-and-convert-hostport-to-inetsocketaddress), I created the following validator method that seems to suit simple validation needs quite nicely. By reading the JavaDoc of URI I removed some false positives such as "host:80" and "hostname/page", but I cannot guarantee there are some false positives left.

```
public static boolean isValidHostNameSyntax(String candidateHost) {
    if (candidateHost.contains("/")) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        // WORKAROUND: add any scheme and port to make the resulting URI valid
        return new URI("my://userinfo@" + candidateHost + ":80").getHost() != null;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. Let's say:

```
public boolean isHostnameValid(String hostname) {
    try {
        InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname); // throws an error when the hostnme could not be found, if so, then return false
        return true;
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        return false;
    }
}
```