# how to validate ipv4 ipv6 and dns name?

Tags: java, android

In Java, there is `InetAdress` which can do the validation. The problem is that it requires accessing the network for the dns query. How can I do the validation? There are hostname and ipv4 regex, But I can't find a regex to match ipv6 address.

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208814/validate-ipv4-ipv6-and-hostname and here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114595/java-regex-for-accepting-a-valid-hostname-ipv4-or-ipv6-address

Comment: @Nurlan Nabiyev I'll checkout InetAdressValidator

Answer (score 0):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can parse host names, IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, without triggering DNS lookup. Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Sample code:

```java
HostName host = new HostName(hostStr);
try {
    host.validate();
    if(host.isAddress()) {
        System.out.println("address: " + host.asAddress());
    } else {
        System.out.println("host name: " + host);
    }
} catch(HostNameException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

This will not do DNS lookup.  More [sample code at the wiki](https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress/wiki/Code-Examples#parse-and-check-if-string-is-an-ip-address-or-host-name)